# No sound with VLC on raspbian

Tags: raspbian, audio, pulseaudio, vlc

I just re-installed raspbian on a PI3: after a raspbian update (apt update/upgrade):
. there was sound with VLC, but video freezed
. there was video with OMXplayer, but no sound
. KODI was working as usual on .ts downloaded files (it crashes with .mkv from avidemux since i moved from 16.04 to 18.04 on my Ubuntu tower)

I do not have the problem on a PI 4 that was not upgraded.

Weel, coming back to the PI3, with a "new" raspbian:
. KODI is working as before
. OMXplayer is now working
. VLC shows the video, but there is no sound. On the last trial I got a 'pulseaudio server connection failure: connection refused'.

PulseAudio is not installed. 
1. Why does VLC try to use it ?
2. Shoul I install pulseaudio ?

Thanks for your help